# Chrome extension HTML Tree Generator is not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am learning DOM (Document Object Model) so I have installed HTML Tree Generator to view the hierarchy, but whenever I start the extension it loads only instead of showing the tree. If it has any bug so is there any other extension similar to this? I have attached the screenshot for more help. [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really get the benefit over simple browser inspecting, but one of the reviews say:

> One needs to go to "Manage Settings" and then enable "Allow access to
>   file URLs" before it will work. otherwise you will just see "Loading"
>   when you try to use it.

Comment: Thanks, Gergely. It works for me. How did you know this?

Comment: As I said one of the reviews says that. (In the Chrome Webstore). I went there to check what this extension does exactly and saw it.

Answer (score 3):

Just right click on HTML Tree generator and select manage extension n then allow access to URLs...

Answer (score 1):

When you see in local webpages, you need to allow the extension to read local files or else it will show `Loading...`

HOWTO: Right click on `Tree Generator Extension` icon   -->   `Manage Extension`     -->    enable `Allow access to file URLs`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable "**Allow access to file URLs**" before it will work. otherwise you will just see "Loading" when you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the three dots (kebab menu) on the top right of your browser. (Google Chrome)
2. Then go to Extensions and click on the Manage Extensions.
3. Then find the HTML Tree Generator extension under My Extensions and click on the "Details" button.
4. Then turn on the toggle switch in the "Allow access to file URLs"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).